# PyCharm "Run with python console" causes Qt freeze?

Tags: python, qt, pycharm, ipython, freeze

I am new to PyCharm, and trying to set it up so I can run whatever script is open in a new IPython console. In "Edit configurations" I have checked "Run with python console". When I run any script attempting to show a Qt window, the window is frozen / not responding. For example:

```
import pyqtgraph
a = pyqtgraph.PlotWindow()
```

or

```
import pylab
pylab.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,1])
```

leads to a frozen plot window.

In Spyder (my previous IDE), running this would bring up an unfrozen / interactive window, and you could also access its properties via the command line. In PyCharm, the window is frozen.

Any ideas? I'm on Windows 10 with PyCharm 2022.1 community and Miniconda Python 3.9.